# Scene color changes by default

Tags: javafx-8

it been like every time, when I try  to update something on the scene, the scene changes it colour to white which is by default. any help would be appreciated.

```
    p = new Player();
    p.walk();

    scene  = new Scene(pane,600,400,Color.BLACK);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: What does "updating something in your scene" mean here? There's hardly enough info in the question to identify the problem. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: updating mean, when I try to render a label or circle on the screen

Comment: "Label or circle"? I would think this would happen only if you rendered a label (or, to be precise, a control or subclass thereof). It shouldn't happen if you only render a circle.